# Оптимизация запроса по скорости

Tags: оптимизация, mysql

Есть таблица машин cars (500.000 записей) и таблица марок авто - marki (20.000 записей). Соединяем их, выбирая определенные марки

```
select * from
  cars,
  makri
WHERE
  marki.id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
AND
  cars.marka_id=marki.id
```

Запрос очень простой, выполняется 0.0030 сек. Если добавить

```
order by cars.name ASC
```

Запрос выполняется ~15 секунд. В phpmyadmin видно, что 95% времени занимает copy to tmp table. Если не применять сортировку, то не будет временной таблицы.

Как мне применять сортировку в таком случае?

p.s. индексы есть во всех полях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить индекс (marka_id, name). А запрос переписать в виде:

```
select * 
from cars 
  join makri on 
    cars.marka_id=marki.id and
    cars.marka_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
order by cars.name
```

Comment: да, если mysql в explain'е будет настаивать на других индексах, используйте [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/index-hints.html).

Comment: Этот результат работает в точности так же как и предидущий. Точно так же создает временную таблицу ровно такое же время. 

Скорее всего проблема в том, что во временной таблице происходит сортировка. Да, это логично, т.к. в маленькой  таблице будет сортировка быстрее, нежели в полной таблице. НО в этом случае индекс не используется и не может быть использован для сортировки. Сколько пишу запросы, пожалуй первый раз столкнулся с таким легким запросом и сложным его ответом.

Comment: Не заметил совет с индексом сразу. USE INDEX решил проблему. Спасибо Юрий!

Comment: Продолжается решаться проблема. Задал новый вопрос, т.к. уже немного не связаные темы

http://hashcode.ru/questions/142351/mysql-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-use-index-ignore-index-force-index

Answer (score 2):

Если данные в таблице меняются не часто их можно заранее отсортировать по нужному полю

```
ALTER TABLE cars ORDER BY name ASC;
```

тогда в запросе не нужно будет указывать ORDER BY.

Comment: К сожалению сортировка может быть по id и по name.