# Сортировка большого количества записей: USE INDEX / IGNORE INDEX / FORCE INDEX

Tags: сортировка, mysql

Проблема казалось бы решена в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/142263/mysql-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), но проблема в следующем:

Когда я сортирую большое количество записей, то **INGORE INDEX (field)** помогает. Но если записей очень мало - **INGORE INDEX** начинает тормозить, по мере снижения выбранных записей. Тут выручает **FORCE INDEX** (field). Но с **FORCE INDEX** при больших объемах начинает тормозить. Неужели прийдется узнать колличество записей с которыми я буду работать прежде чем выбрать нужен ли тут индекс или нет? :)

P.S. USE INDEX на усмотрение mysql оптимизатора тоже не помогает

Comment: Да, универсального метода тут нету, скорее всего. Можно поиграться индексами. Например использовать индекс по name, можно попробовать переставить поля в составном индексе. Выбрать средний вариант для всего спектра запросов (по количеству записей в том числе).  

Поищите еще варианты на [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/)...

Comment: может проблема не в субд а в самом приложении? вы можете изменить алгоритм работы с СУБД так чтоб работать с ограниченными наборами данных.